# R: Calculating the norm from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've this data frame:

```
coef variable value
1        1    0e+00
2        1    1e-05
1        2    0e+00
2        2    2e-05
```

I'm trying to calculate the **L1** norm of the column **value** based on the column **variable**. So, if **variable=1**, I want to calculate the norm where **value is 0e+00 and 1e-05**. When **variable=2** I want to calculate the norm for **value 0e+00 and 2e-05** and so on...

So the result should look like this:

```
coef variable value norm
1        1    0e+00 1e-05
2        1    1e-05 1e-05
1        2    0e+00 2e-05
2        2    2e-05 2e-05
```

Here is the code that I did so far:

```
    #creating the data frame
       coef = c(1, 2, 1,2) 
        variable = c(1,1,2,2) 
        value = c(0e+00, 1e-05, 0e+00, 2e-05) 
        df = data.frame(coef, variable, value) 

    #this part is not working correctly because df$value is not a matrix
        for(k in 1:2){
          if(df$variable==1){
            df$norm=norm(df$value, type="1")
          }
        }
```

Is it possible to calculate the norm from data frame values ?

Comment: What "norm" are you referring to? The norm of a matrix? The Euclidean (L2) norm? The .... norm? You pass a numeric vector to `norm` (which takes a `matrix`), so I'm unsure about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  I just added it, the L1 norm, sorry I forgot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'variable', we can wrap the `matrix` call on 'value' to convert to a single column `matrix`, and get the 'norm', create that column within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(variable) %>% 
   mutate(Norm = norm(matrix(value))) %>%
   as.data.frame
#  coef variable value  Norm
#1    1        1 0e+00 1e-05
#2    2        1 1e-05 1e-05
#3    1        2 0e+00 2e-05
#4    2        2 2e-05 2e-05
```